# Moving <td> to higher row when other <td> has been removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row

I have an table of images which is 4xM length:

```
<tr>
<td id='1'><div ...><img src=.../></div></td>
<td id='2'><div ...><img src=.../></div></td>
<td id='3'><div ...><img src=.../></div></td>
<td id='4'><div ...><img src=.../></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id='5'><div><img src=.../></div></td>
...
```

On every image I have an `onClick='RemoveImg(id);'` to remove it's `<td>` tag:

```
function RemoveImg(id)
{
$('#'+id).remove();
}
```

After I remove for example td with id=3 my html look like this:

```
<tr>
<td id='1'><div ...><img src=.../></div></td>
<td id='2'><div ...><img src=.../></div></td>
<td id='4'><div ...><img src=.../></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id='5'><div><img src=.../></div></td>
...
```

How can I make it td with id=5, from row below moves up and look like this

```
  <tr>
<td id='1'><div ...><img src=.../></div></td>
<td id='2'><div ...><img src=.../></div></td>
<td id='4'><div ...><img src=.../></div></td>
<td id='5'><div ...><img src=.../></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get rid of the table rows altogether and use CSS to float the divs next to each other within a fixed width container.  Then it would happen automagically

```
<div id="container">
    <div id='1'><img src=.../></div>
    <div id='2'><img src=.../></div>
    <div id='3'><img src=.../></div>
    <div id='4'><img src=.../></div>
    <div id='5'><img src=.../></div>
</div>
```

With accompanying CSS

```
#container {
    width: {fixed_width};
}

#container div {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: To expand on the answer, this isn't the right use of a table. Tables are for tabular data. You have a grid-type layout. Floated elements are the correct choice. See http://960.gs/ or http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem for examples of pre-built systems.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question is that you always want 4 items in a row. You would need to loop over each row moving the first td from the next row up.

Alternatively, you could consider using ul/li and floating each list item. If you put a width on the ul, the li children will automatically wrap for you when one is removed or added. This also would work with any floated element should your content be larger. Let me know if you'd like an example.

Answer (score 0):

Code sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g6RaB/1/) removes 3rd column from first row and adds first column from second row to first row.

```
    function RemoveImg(columntoRemove, columntoAppend)
    {
      $('#'+columntoRemove).remove();
      var col5 = $("#" + columntoAppend).clone();
      $("#abctable tr:first").append(col5);
    };
```